# Error al querer correr "npm run serve"

Tags: vue.js, github, npm

Acabo de clonar un repositorio de Github, trabaja con Vue pero me sale el siguiente error cuando le pongo "npm run serve"

```
> save-editor@0.1.0 serve C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
(node:6800) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6800) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6800) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6800) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:725
          throw error;
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
    at C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\src\server\api\index.js:235:18
    at C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:722:9
    at C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:216:23
    at C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:274:21
    at parseConnectionString (C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:542:12)
    at connect (C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:272:3)
    at C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:215:5
    at maybePromise (C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:719:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:211:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (C:\laragon\www\thps-save-editor\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421:22)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! save-editor@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the save-editor@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-24T18_05_37_664Z-debug.log
```

Pude llevar a cabo el git clone y el npm install sin problema, pero en esta parte no entiendo.

En Visual Studio Code me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
"Vetur can't find 'tsconfig.json' or 'jsconfig.json'"
```

Vue: @vue/cli 4.5.13

NPM: 6.14.14

Repositorio https://github.com/chc/thps-save-editor

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Al correr `npm install` no salen errores? No sale algo más en logs cuando haces `npm run serve`?

Comment: No hay cuando pongo ```npm install```, pondré todo lo que me sale del error. Gracias.

Comment: Hola, hago un comentario adicional. Lo que pasa que en Visual Studio Code me aparece este mensaje: ```"Vetur can't find 'tsconfig.json' or 'jsconfig.json'``` tendrá algo que ver? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero necesitas tener instalado MongoDB (no lo dice en el README del proyecto para ser justos).

Yo usé docker para instalar MongoDB:

- Primero descargas la imagen: `docker pull mongo:5.0.2`
- Iniciar una instancia de mongo sin autenticación: `docker run --name some-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:5.0.2`
- Creas la base de datos **SaveEditor** con tu cliente de mongo favorito

Luego vas a necesitar cargar una variable de ambiente antes de iniciar el servidor: `export MONGODB_URI='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'`

Cuando tengas todo esto entonces ya podrías iniciar el servidor: `npm run serve`.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Solución para MacOS, requisitos:

1. Instalar NodeJS, https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Instalar MongoDB, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Al tener instalado MongoDB y al haber terminado las instrucciones del link que publiqué, los siguientes comandos son necesarios y se utilizan para empezar o terminar los servicios de MongoDB.

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

Para detener

```
brew services stop mongodb-community@5.0
```

Después de haber instalado MongoDB y haber empezado los servicios, el `npm run serve` ya no arrojó errores y llegué a la misma conclusión de la respuesta aceptada, para MacOS.